# Is there a PHP function for retrieving the "first part" of a URL?

Tags: php, built-in

Is there a PHP function for retrieving the "first part" of a URL, similar to how `dirname`/`basename` act on file paths?

Something along the lines of

```
echo "url_basename('example.com/this_post/12312')"
```

which would return

```
example.com
```

Comment: If you're running a recent version of PHP you could do `echo explode('/', 'example.com/this_post/12312')[0];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) should do this reliably.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code to output example.com with your given URL:

```
$url = 'example.com/this_post/12312';

if (strpos($url,'http') === FALSE) {
    $url = 'http://'.$url;
}

$arrURLParts = parse_url($url);
$host = $arrURLParts['host'];
echo $host;
```

**Warning:** if you omit the part to ensure the URL starts with http then parse_url would return an empty host and put 'example.com/this_post/12312' into $arrURLParts['path'] instead.